# Placing existing VCL controls on a TPanel component

Tags: c++, controls, vcl, tpanel

As we all know, `TPanel` is a container for other visual components (`TLabel`, `TEdit` etc).
However, it seems that we can place only new components (from the
component palette) onto an existing TPanel and the VCL framework will then automatically make the TPanel their parent).

I wonder if there's a way to place existing visual components (those that are already on our VCL form) onto a TPanel. I've tried

- Placing components on an existing TPanel (this doesn't work because 
  the framework will not make the TPanel their parent)
- Manually editing the form's dfm file (the components on the TPanel
  are now invisible -- a bug?)
- Explicitly setting a component's Parent property in code (`Label1` is visible even when `Panel1` height is set to 0)

  ```
  Label1->Parent = Panel1;
  ```

Neither of the above worked but this seems to be such a basic thing that it has to be a way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Tried to move the controls in the tree of the structure view?

Comment: I've tried to edit the dfm manually so that the controls are children of the TPanel in question. Didn't work. The controls are now completely invisible.

Comment: What happens when you try to move the controls in the tree of the structure view? You should also look at the `Left` and `Top` properties.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'move the controls in the tree of structure view'? I think  I can only move the controls manually at design-time or by editing the dfm file. Anyway, if nothing else works, I'll simply add new controls to my TPanel and that'll work but this is slightly more work.

Comment: The IDE has a view called "Structure" wich shows the structure of the form at design time. You can open it via the main menu "View". There you can drag and drop items to change their parent.

Comment: OK, will give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152150/discussion-between-kerem-d-and-dsp-user).

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience with *VCL* (I use *Delphi* but I think the same is valid for *C++*), I know 3 ways to change the `Parent` of an already existing control at design time:

- Drag and drop the `Control` into the desired `Parent` from the *Structure window*
  [image]
- Select the `Control`, cut it <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd>, select the desired `Parent` and paste <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>. In this way the `Control` will be pasted as child control of the desired `Parent`
- Manually edit the *DFM file*. Doing this way, you have to pay attenction to the `Left` and `Top` properties, because the `Control` could be placed outside the new `Parent` and it could seems invisible. In this case I suggest to set the control's `Left` and `Top` to `0` in order to be sure the `Control` will be visible inside its new `Parent`

Comment: Yes, the second method works as already suggested by Kerem D (thanks Kerem). I wasn't able to make the third method work even when Left and Top look OK (they seem to be within the bounds of its parent control). I will still upvote your answer.